# How to remotely restart sshd?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, connection, telnet

When I try to connect to the ubuntu server, I get timeouts, `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`. Most of the answers suggest a reboot, but I'm unable to physically reboot it since the building is locked down due to COVID. Is there a way to remotely restart the `sshd` service?

This is the error messages from trying to SSH and telnet for the port. Any suggests to reboot the sshd? Thank you

```
user~$ ssh server_user@server_ip
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
user:~$ telnet server_ip 22
Trying 192.168.1.1...
Connected to server_ip.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Also note that "timeout" and "connection reset by peer" is not the same.